# How to filter data from a parent component in a child component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a component who show a list of data and I want to filter this list with different filters who are in a child component

I managed to do it with "computed" but only when I put everything in the parent component.

```
Test.vue
<template>
   <div>
     <filtres />
     <garage v-for="g in garages" v-bind:gar="g" :key="g.id" />
   </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
name: 'test',
components: {
  simplecomposant,
  garage,
  filtres
},
  data(){
      return{
        garages: [],
      }
  },
  mounted(){
      var self = this;
        axios.get('FETCHAPI').then(function (response)
        {
          self.garages = response.data.datas;
        });
  },
}   
</script>

Filtres.vue
<template>
  <div>
    <label><input type="radio" v-model="selectedCity" value="All" /> All</label>
    <label><input type="radio" v-model="selectedCity" value="1" /> City 1</label>
    <label><input type="radio" v-model="selectedCity" value="2" />City 2</label>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {

  name : 'filtres',
  data(){
      return{
        selectedCity : "All"
      }
  },
}
</script>

garage.vue
<template>
  <li class="aeris-simple-li">{{gar.name}}</span></li>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name : 'garage',
  props: {
      gar: {
         type: Object
     }
  },
}
</script>
```

I want that when I select a filter (all, city 1, ...) it filters the datas "garages" who are in the parent component.

Comment: `$emit` an event whenever a filter changes in your filter child component, listen to it in the paren (`@filter-changed="updateFilters"`) and use a computed property in your parent that returns your data filtered by all set filters.

Comment: thanks ! it works !