# How can I filter an array in a parent component from a filter in a child component

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I have a parent component which v-fors over an array of objects.  I have a child component which displays a list of possible filters which to filter the parent list on.  I'm using an `event bus` to emit a message when a filter has been picked.  I just can't seem to put the pieces together.  I like the idea a computed property, but how does that know when the filter has changed and should redo the v-for.  I've tried a method, but can't seem to get that to work either.

[How to filter data from a parent component in a child component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54343716/how-to-filter-data-from-a-parent-component-in-a-child-component) seems to be close to what I want to do, but without a solid example of how to make it work, I can't see how to put it together.

Child Component:

```
export default {
  name: "mechanisms",
  props: ['games'],
  data() {
    return {
      inactiveMechanisms: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggleActive(mechanism) {
      const idx = this.inactiveMechanisms.indexOf(mechanism);
      idx !== -1 ? this.inactiveMechanisms.splice(idx, 1) : this.inactiveMechanisms.push(mechanism);
      this.emitFilterClick();
    },
    emitFilterClick() {
      EventBus.$emit('mechanism-filter-change', this.inactiveMechanisms);
    }
  },
  computed: {
    allMechanisms() {
      const mechanisms = this.games.reduce((acc, game) => {
        game.mechanics.forEach((mechanism) => {
          acc.push(mechanism);
        });
        return acc;
      }, [])
      const uniqeMechanisms = Array.from(new Set(mechanisms).values()).sort();
      this.inactiveMechanisms = [];
      return uniqeMechanisms;
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

Parent:

```
<mechanisms-filter v-bind:games="sortedGames" />
<div class="games" 
    v-bind:key=game.bggId v-for="game in filteredGames">
</div>

computed: {
    sortedGames() {
      return showBestAtFirst(this.userNames.length, [...this.games].sort(compareGameNames));
    },
    filteredGames() {
      return this.sortedGames;
    },
    showFilters() {
      return this.inactiveMechanisms;
    }
  }
```

I don't know what/how filteredGames should be structured so that it will update when the 'mechanism-filter-change' event is triggered.  Making it a computed prop makes more sense than a method, but I don't know how to tell the computed prop that inactiveMechanisms changed.

Thanks

Comment: can you provide a bit more code, a [mcve] would be helpful

Comment: I think I figured out the solution.  This doc (http://optimizely.github.io/vuejs.org/guide/computed.html) helped me out a ton.  I think what I was missing was that I needed to include `this.inactiveMechanisms` as a dependency in `filteredGames`.  Once that was included in the computed prop, it worked.